# Root system of a simple lie algebra is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

[image]

The proposition is from Humphreys.

I don't understand how to prove the highlighted statements. How can I express a general element of K? I tried using Cartan decomposition of L but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is nothing to prove. We have $[K,L_{\beta}]=0$ by the definition of $K$ and because of $[L_{\alpha},L_{\beta}]\subseteq L_{\alpha+\beta}=0$. For the meaning of "centralized" and "normalized" see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer).

Comment: My problem is the meaning of "subalgebra generated by". Is it the direct sum of the generators?

Comment: @magnetissimo The subalgebra generated by a set of elements $A$ is the smallest subalgebra containing $A$. A subalgebra is a subspace closed under the bracket.